# Swift: "This class is not key value coding-compliant..." for Double values

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-coding

I have a scenario in which I have a simple data object in Swift, containing multiple property variables.  They are a mix of `String?` and `Double?` value types.  I'm trying to retrieve the values for each property using `valueForKey`.  My code looks something like this...

```
let myDataObj = ...
let stringKeyName = "myStringProperty"
let doubleKeyName = "myDoubleProperty"

guard let stringPropertyValue = myDataObj.valueForKey(stringKeyName) else {
    return
}
guard let doublePropertyValue = myDataObj.valueForKey(doubleKeyName) else {
    return
}
```

The first call to get `stringPropertyValue` works fine, and I am able to retrieve the value as expected.  However, the second call to retrieve `doublePropertyValue` fails with an exception saying, "`this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myDoubleProperty.'`"

I know that the property name is correct, and I also know that a value is set for this property.  Why is it that `valueForKey` works on `String` objects, but not `Double` objects?

Comment: So, your data object is a subclass of NSObject? KVC is not native for swift

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I am sub classing NSObject

Comment: I've tried to do the same way. It worked for "Double", "NSNumber?", but not for "Double?". seems like native swift types can not be converted to Objective-C when they are optionals.

Comment: `Double?` type has no equevelent in Objective c. and that is the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct, you can only do key value coding for types that can be represented in Objective-C. Unfortunately, those types that are represented as primitive data types in Objective-C (e.g. Swift's `Int` and `Double` are represented as `NSInteger` and `double` in Objective-C, respectively) can not be presented as such if they are optionals. In Objective-C, optionals only make sense with class types, not fundamental data types.