# setValueForKeys is failing Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code in the Playground:

```
class Pokemon : NSObject {

    var name :String!
    var id :Int?
    var imageURL :String!
    var latitude :Double!
    var longitude :Double!

    init(dictionary :[String:Any]) {

        super.init()
        setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
}
}

let dict :[String:Any] = ["name":"John","imageURL":"someimageURL","latitude":45.67]
let pokemon = Pokemon(dictionary: dict)
```

When the call to setValuesForKeys is made then it throws an exception saying the following:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__lldb_expr_13.Pokemon 0x6000000ffd00> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key latitude.'
```

I have the key "latitude" but for some reason it is not able to find it. Any ideas!

Comment: Why create such an initializer? Why not create a proper initializer or set the properties directly?

Comment: Absolutely! But I want to find out what I am doing wrong in the above code. Also, this initializer would be helpful if you are setting lots of properties.

Comment: How about [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26366082/3476191) then?

Comment: @NobodyNada Nope! Please read my question before linking it to some other question. I am explicitly using setValuesForKeys function.

Comment: @johndoe It's the same exact problem, just a different symptom -- types like `int` and `double`, which cannot be optional in Objective-C are not bridged to Objective-C.

Comment: why not `var name: String  = ""` and `var imageURL: String = ""`?

Comment: @johndoe you should read Reflecting on Reflection at the end of this post  https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37

Comment: BTW why are you subclassing NSObject? Looks meaningless. You should use a struct for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type `Double!` (similarly `Double?`) has no correspondence in the Objective-C world, so [it is not exposed as an Objective-C property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34793782/swift-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-double-values), so Key-Value Coding cannot find a key named "latitude" and crash.

You should convert those fields to non-optional if you need KVC.

```
class Pokemon : NSObject {
    var name: String!
    var id: Int = 0
    var imageURL: String!
    var latitude: Double = 0.0
    var longitude: Double = 0.0

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        super.init()
        setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
    }
}
```

Comment: And String! or String? has correspondence in Objective-C world.

Comment: @johndoe Yes, those become `NSMutableString*` in ObjC.